# Register new user, assign custom role then send email

Tags: filters, users, actions, user-registration, notifications

I have a very specific user registration process to implement on a website.
I need to follow these steps when a user register via the front-end form :

1. check email domain

   - if whitelisted domain: regular wordpress workflow (user registered, email notifications sent then user can choose is password during the first authentication process)
2. If blacklisted domain

   - create user in DB
   - assign a custom WP role (eg. 'temp_account') for this user
   - don't send regular wordpress mail notifications
   - user with 'temp_account' role can't login

I can't find the proper action/filter I need to use for checking the email then prevent wordpress from sending default notifications...

Any advice/suggestion would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

TO really fit your needs, I think it's better to rewrite some part of `wp_insert_user()` function, some part can interrest you

```
   $user_email = apply_filters( 'pre_user_email', $raw_user_email );
```

And :

```
   $illegal_logins = (array) apply_filters( 'illegal_user_logins', array() );

if ( in_array( strtolower( $user_login ), array_map( 'strtolower', $illegal_logins ) ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', __( 'Sorry, that username is not allowed.' ) );
}
```

And :

```
     if ( isset( $userdata['role'] ) ) {
         $user->set_role( $userdata['role'] );
     } elseif ( ! $update ) {
         $user->set_role(get_option('default_role'));
     }
```

I think you'll be able to combine all these parts to make your own user registration.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi @Benoti ! I know I need to change/override this `wp_insert_user()` behavior but I'm not very comfortable with the idea of a "function rewriting"... I would rather use filters or actions.

Comment: Unfortunatly as you can see, there is no filter or action at this step :-(

Comment: I think maybe I can use one(or both) `user_register`or `register_new_user` actions but I can't find the right spot to check the email and force custom role before notifications are sent...

Comment: I think thèse functions are just to register with default parameter. But you maybe can use the filter of $illegal_logins if you only allow user name/login as email ?